# Can't update database

Tags: java, mysql

my APP:niaola.cloudfoundry.com
java 1.6
mysql5.1

select code

```
     update yy_desklist set isok=? where 
     isok=? and timedrelease<=? Parameters: [1, 0, 1358929049]
```

error log:

```
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
      Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: UPDATE command denied to user 'uHHztgqtQsbK9'@
      '172.30.49.102' for table 'yy_desklist' Query: update yy_desklist set 
       isok=? where isok=? and timedrelease<=? Parameters: [1, 0, 1358929049]
                at org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner.rethrow(QueryRunner.java:542)
                at org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner.update(QueryRunner.java:599)
                at com.niaola.yangyun.db.QueryHelper.update(QueryHelper.java:300)
                ... 44 more
      com.niaola.yangyun.db.DBException: java.sql.SQLException: UPDATE command denied
      to user 'uHHztgqtQsbK9'@'172.30.49.102' for table 'yy_desklist' Query: update 
      yy_desklist set isok=? where isok=? and timedrelease<=? 
      Parameters: [1, 0,1358930631] at com.niaola.yangyun.db.QueryHelper.update(QueryHelper.java:302)
      at com.niaola.yangyun.mvc.TempletsClass.getTimedList(TempletsClass.java:57)
```

Comment: you don't have permissions use GRANT query

Comment: Looks like a permission issue to me.

Answer (score 1):

The user "uHHztgqtQsbK9" seems not to have update permission.

You need to grant the required permissions using an admin user.

```
GRANT  SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON `db`.* TO 'user'@'host';
```

For a more detailed explanation you should consult the [Mysql Documentation - Account Management Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/account-management-sql.html)